C++ multiple producer multiple consumer lock-free queue - where is my error?
I implemented the following multiple producer multiple consumer lock-free queue, however it crashes when I run it, inside dequeue function with "std::bad_alloc" exception. I don't understand why bad_alloc is thrown, I do not allocate any memory and do not use any STL containers that could allocate.
Where am I wrong?
    class QuoteQueue {
        public:
    
            QuoteQueue() {
                // Make sure that atomic which we use is lock free:
                assert(numOfElements_.is_lock_free());
            }
    
            // Blocks if the queue is full
            void enqueue(Quote&& quote) {
                try
                {
                    
                    while(numOfElements_.fetch_add(1) >= MAX_CAPACITY) {
                        numOfElements_.fetch_sub(1);
                    }
                    
                    int curTail = 0;
                    int newTail = 0;
    
                    do {
                        curTail = tail_.load();
                        newTail = (curTail + 1) % MAX_CAPACITY;
                    } while(!tail_.compare_exchange_weak(curTail, newTail));
    
                    quotes_[curTail] = quote;
                }
                catch(std::exception& e)
                {
                    std::cout << "exception during enqueue: " << e.what() << std::endl;
                }
            }
    
            // Blocks if the queue is empty
            Quote dequeue() {
                
                try
                {
    
                    while(numOfElements_.fetch_sub(1) <= 0) {
                        numOfElements_.fetch_add(1);
                    }
                    
                    int curHead = 0;
                    int newHead = 0;
    
                    do {
                        curHead = head_.load();
                        newHead = (curHead + 1) % MAX_CAPACITY;
                    }
                    while(!head_.compare_exchange_weak(curHead, newHead));
    
                    return quotes_[curHead];
                }
                catch(std::exception& e)
                {
                    std::cout << "exception during dequeue: " << e.what() << std::endl;
                }
                
                return {};
            }
    
        private:
            static const int MAX_CAPACITY = 1000;
    
            std::array<Quote, MAX_CAPACITY> quotes_;
    
            std::atomic<int> head_ = 0;
            std::atomic<int> tail_ = 0;
    
            std::atomic<int> numOfElements_ = 0;
    };

int main() {

    std::vector<std::thread> enqThreads;
    std::vector<std::thread> deqThreads;

    QuoteQueue queue;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        enqThreads.emplace_back([&queue] {
                int count = 0;
                while (1) {
                    Quote quote({"2024-02-12 13:12:13:567.788", 100. + count, 50. + count * 0.5, true});
                    queue.enqueue(std::move(quote));
                    count = (count + 1) % 100;
                    //std::cout << quote << std::flush;
                }
            });
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        deqThreads.emplace_back([&queue]
        {
            while (1) {
                auto quote = queue.dequeue(); // dequeue should block if queue is empty
                quote.produc = false;
                //std::cout << quote << std::flush; // [Leonid] I added flush for testing
            }
        });
    }

    // Your code goes here.
    // Wait for enqueue, dequeue threads to finisih

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        enqThreads[i].join();
        deqThreads[i].join();
    }
    
    return 0;
}

Output:
exception during dequeue: std::bad_alloc
Segmentation fault

Your CAS loop is re-loading head_ unnecessarily, but that's not the cause. We don't know what Quote is and where std::bad_alloc is getting thrown exactly. Please provide a [mre].

In dequeue() nothing prevents quotes_[curHead] from being replaced before it's returned.  I'd think being able to update elements of quotes_ while it could be in the process of being read from another thread is a race condition and you're therefore invoking UB.

@AndrewHenle thanks for your response; my reasoning was that the value of curHead must be unique for each thread, because it is loaded atomically from head_; also each thread changes head_ atomically. And so quotes_[curHead] cannot be changed by other threads. (theoretically if number of threads is much bigger than MAX_CAPACITY it might happen, but this is not the case).

@JanSchultke I load curHead in the loop as I must be sure that head_ = curHead + 1 (after it is incremented). So if this fails, I need to repeat it again, that's why the loop comes. Is there a way to do this differently?

I edited my question: added my main() function and the output which is printed.

@AndreyRubliov each thread changes head_ atomically.  And once thread A gets its value of curHead so it can return quotes_[curHead], head_ has changed, so thread B can then immediately overwrite thread A's  quotes_[curHead].  Once head_ changes, whatever used to be the head_ value is immediately fair game to get nuked.

@AndrewHenle compare_exchange already loads the most recent value when it fails. You only need load() once at the beginning.

@JanSchultke It's not the load that's the problem - it's the fact that after the atomic load-and-update of head_, the resulting position in the queue specified by curHead is unprotected from modification by another thread.  That'd be a race condition and UB.

Strictly speaking this isn't lock-free since it is blocking. But more importantly, your logic is broken. You block if the queue is full or empty, which is based on numberOfElements. However, if this check passes, you unconditionally operate on your buffer. For example, suppose an enqueue operation has increased numberOfElements, but has not yet updated tail. Then a dequeue can also successfully pass the empty check and return some random data.
